# Mongodb Sharding - no such command: 'addShard'

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to configure sharding in one machine and I keep getting an error message when trying to add shards. I'm using the following website as a reference: http://www.javahotchocolate.com/notes/mongodb-sharding.html

I'm using a single machine and using different ports to simulate the different IPs.

I have a configuration as follows:

Replica set members:

```
mongod --dbpath \rs1_p\db --port 27017 --replSet rs1
mongod --dbpath \rs1_s1\db --port 27018 --replSet rs1
mongod --dbpath \rs1_s2\db --port 27019 --replSet rs1
mongod --dbpath \rs1_p\db --port 47017 --replSet rs2
mongod --dbpath \rs1_s1\db --port 47018 --replSet rs2
mongod --dbpath \rs1_s2\db --port 47019 --replSet rs2
```

Configuring replica sets in MongoDB shell:

```
config =
{
    _id:"rs1",
    members:
    [
        { _id:0, host:"computerName:27017" },
        { _id:1, host:"computerName:27018" },
        { _id:2, host:"computerName:27019" }
    ]
}
rs.initiate( config )

config =
{
    _id:"rs2",
    members:
    [
        { _id:0, host:"computerName:47017" },
        { _id:1, host:"computerName:47018" },
        { _id:2, host:"computerName:47019" }
    ]
}
rs.initiate( config )
```

Launching configuration servers:

```
mongod --dbpath \c1\db --configsvr --port 37017
mongod --dbpath \c2\db --configsvr --port 37018
mongod --dbpath \c3\db --configsvr --port 37019
```

Launching sharding routers:

```
mongos --port 27077 --configdb computerName:37017, computerName:37018, computerName:37019
mongos --port 27078 --configdb computerName:37017, computerName:37018, computerName:37019
```

All okay until here, but In getting an error message in the next step

```
sh.addShard('rs1/computerName:27017')
```

I'm getting the follow error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0.0,   
    "errmsg" : "no such command: 'addShard', bad cmd: '{ addShard: \"rs1/computerName:27017\" }'",
"code" : 59
}
```

I can not seem to get around from this error message.

Any ideas on what am I missing.

Thanks

Comment: upvoted for sharing very helpful link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as per documentation

> Run addShard when connected to a ***mongos*** instance. The command takes the following form when adding a single database instance as a shard

when you run this connected to mongo shell you will get that error, so you need to connect to let say `mongo --port 27078` and issue that command.

```
mongo --host <hostname of machine running mongos> --port <port mongos listens on>
```

[manaual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#add-shards-to-the-cluster)

more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/addShard/#dbcmd.addShard) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-sharding/)