# error Setting up sharded mongodb cluster in localhost

Tags: mongodb, sharding

while register shards with our mongos query router gives error

1. start mongo --port 27011 --host localhost

then  adding sh.addShard("localhost:27012") gives error

{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no such command: 'addShard', bad cmd: '{ addShard: \"localhost:27012\" }'",
    "code" : 59,
    "codeName" : "CommandNotFound"
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb Sharding - no such command: 'addShard'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768562/mongodb-sharding-no-such-command-addshard)

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768562/mongodb-sharding-no-such-command-addshard)